# (Auto) Searching for every SMB Share in Network and List which has ,,Everyone" Read + Write access

Tags: powershell, server-message-block

Is there an comfortable way (example with PowerShell) to do a network scan for every share and list the shares which has setup that ,,Everyone" can Read and Write.

Comment: Please note that ServerFault is not a free script writing service.  We request and require that all questions include research effort and/or examples of what you've already tried.

Comment: Note that this is the default, standard share permission set so hopefully this is most, if not all of your shares.  It might be easier to look for the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this script: [Scan-Share-Permissions.ps1](https://github.com/ahhh/PSSE/blob/master/Scan-Share-Permissions.ps1) from PowerShell Scripting Expert repository project.